# How to Identify browser reload either through reload button or F5 key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`F5` key code can be used but I don't want to depend on key code since it depends on OS.

```
 $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.which || e.keyCode === 116) {
      isRefresh = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a handler to `window.onbeforeunload`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event){
  console.log(event);
}
```

See: [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload%20mdn-docs)

Comment: This function will be called even when page renders for the first time.

Comment: I need to find out whether the page is refreshed or not.